# multiApply function for loop on a 3D array

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array, apply

I am trying to make my data processing more efficient for a spatial temperature data project. I have a for loop that will do what I want, but it is much too slow for processing multiple years of data. This loop looks at each spatial cell and, based on the 365 temperature values in that year, creates a value for the frequency, duration, number, and temp of heat events that will go into seperate 2d dataframes.

[image]

```
for (b in 1:299) { #longitude
      for (c in 1:424) { #latitude
        data <- year[b,c] #makes all temps into a vector
        for (d in 2:364) {
          if (data[d]>=Threshold & data[d+1]>=Threshold) {
            frequencydf[b,c]=frequencydf[b,c]+1
            tempsdf[b,c]=tempsdf[b,c]+data[d]
            
            }else if (data[d-1]>=Threshold & data[d]>=Threshold & data[d+1]<Threshold) {
              frequencydf[b,c]=frequencydf[b,c]+1
              numberdf[b,c]=numberdf[b,c]+1
              tempsdf[b,c]=tempsdf[b,c]+data[d]
            }else {
              frequencydf[b,c]=frequencydf[b,c]
              numberdf[b,c]=numberdf[b,c]
              tempsdf[b,c]=tempsdf[b,c]
            }
        }
        durationdf[b,c]=frequencydf[b,c]/numberdf[b,c]
        tempsdf[b,c]=tempsdfd[b,c]/frequencydf[b,c]
      }
    })
```

Therefore, I am trying to work with apply fuctions to speed up the process. I think I am running into issues when attempting to analyze each spacial cell by values in the 3rd (time) dimention in my array.

I am starting with the frequency parameter and trying to create the same data frame as above.

```
frequencylist <- Apply(year_array, fun = frequency.calc1, margins=c(1, 2))
  frequencydf <- as.data.frame(frequencylist)
```

Using this function:

```
frequency.calc1 = function(cell) {
  data <- as.vector(cell)
  frequency <- 0
  for (d in 2:364) {
    if (data[d]>=Threshold & data[d+1]>=Threshold) {
      frequency=frequency+1
      
    }else if (data[d-1]>=Threshold & data[d]>=Threshold & data[d+1]<Threshold) {
      frequency=frequency+1
      
    }else {
      frequency=frequency
    }
    return(frequency)
  }
}
```

I am very new to creating functions and using the Apply function so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For-loops and *apply functions run about the same speed. Your problem is all those "if" s.
First of all, you have two separate conditions both of which lead to incrementing `frequency`.  Figure out how to combine them.  Next, remember that the `R` language is vectorized, so you don't need a loop at all.  With a little careful thought, you can write a line something like

```
frequency <-  sum(data[1:N-2] >=threshold & data[2:N-1] >=threshold & data[3:N<threshold)
```

I haven't checked all the ">" vs "<"  but you get the idea.

As a side note,  **NEVER** hard-code the range of a loop.  You can start with  "2" since your conditionals reference "d-1" but let the maximum value be defined as something like `length(data) - 1`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution worked really well for streamlining the process of counting the heat events! Is there a way to transform the sum equation, like you wrote above, to sum the cell values so I can work with the temperatures?

Comment: @sfellows  Sure, but I'm not clear on which values you want to sum over.  This isn't Excel :-) so we call each value an element of a vector (or array), not a "cell" .  But if you can clarify over which dimension of your array data you want to filter and sum, I may be able to propose some code.

Comment: Yes! The data that I am comparing to the threshold are temperatures. The frequency equation will count how many times the temperature goes above the threshold under certain conditions. I would also like to sum the actual values of the temperature data using the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution used to simplify the process is shown below. Sum functions with conditionals were used in place of the if statements. This made the process incredibly efficient and did not use the apply function or an additional function.

```
for (b in 1:299) {
 for (c in 1:424) {
  data <- year[b,c]
    N=length(data)
    frequency[b,c] <- sum(data[1:N] >=Threshold & data[2:N] >=Threshold & data[3:N] <Threshold) + sum(data[1:N] >=Threshold & data[2:N] >=Threshold)
    number[b,c] <- sum(data[1:N] >=Threshold & data[2:N] >=Threshold & data[3:N] <Threshold)
    duration[b,c] <- frequency[b,c]/number[b,c]
    temps[b,c] <- sum(data[data[1:N] >=Threshold & data[2:N] >=Threshold & data[3:N] <Threshold]) + sum(data[data[1:N] >=Threshold & data[2:N] >=Threshold])
    temps[b,c] <- temps[b,c]/frequency[b,c]
}}
```

Thank you for your help @Carl Witthoft